# Null Pointer Exception with a Class array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I keep getting the Null Pointer Exception with my Class.

**Client Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

        count ++;
        System.out.println(i);
        Clip[] newClip = new Clip[100];
        newClip[i] = new Clip();
        menu();
        int option = kb.nextInt();

        switch(option){
            case 1: System.exit(0);
                    break;

            case 2: newClip[i].Input();
                    newClip[i].Output();
                    break;

            case 3: int indexclip = 0;
                    int testclip = 0;
                    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter the index number of the clip: ");
                    testclip = key.nextInt();

                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++){

                        indexclip = newClip[j].getIndex(); // happens here
                        System.out.println(indexclip);
                        if(testclip == indexclip){
                            j = 120;
                            newClip[j].Output(); // and i would assume here too
                        }
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Clip Class:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Clip {

private int index;
private String surname;        
private float length;
private float speed;
private String time = "testing";

public Clip(){
    index = 0;
    surname = "N/A";
    length = (float) 0.00;
    speed = (float) 0.00;
    time = "0:00AM";        
}

public void Output(){
    System.out.println("Index: "+ index);
    System.out.println("Surname: " + surname);
    System.out.println("Length: " + length);
    System.out.println("Speed: "+ speed + "m/s");
    System.out.println("Time: "+ time);


}
public void Input(){
    int testint;
    float testfloat;
    int spacePos;
    String testString;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input an index number between 1 - 10000: ");
    testint = kb.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (testint < 1 || testint > 10000){

            System.out.println("Input an index number between 1 - 10000: ");
            testint = kb.nextInt();

           }

        else {
            i = 120;
        }
    }
    index = testint;

    System.out.println("What is the competitor's Surname and their Given name: ");
    surname = key.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Length of the Tape in seconds: ");
    testfloat = kb.nextFloat();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (testfloat < 1 || testfloat > 60){

            System.out.println("Length of the Tape in seconds: ");
            testfloat = kb.nextFloat();

           }
        else {
            i = 120;
        }
    }
    length = testfloat;

    System.out.println("Estimated Speed of competitor in metres per second: ");
    testfloat = kb.nextFloat();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (testfloat < 7 && testfloat > 13){

            System.out.println("Estimated Speed of competitor in metres per second: ");
            testfloat = kb.nextInt();

           }
        else {
            i = 120;
        }
    }
    speed = testfloat;

    System.out.println("Time of recording between 0900 - 1700: ");
    testString = key.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (testString.length() != 4){
            System.out.println("Time of recording between 09:00 - 17:00: ");
            testString = key.nextLine();
        }
        else {
            i = 120;
        }
    }
    time = testString;
}

public int getIndex(){
    return index;
}

public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}

public float getLength(){
    return length;
}

public float getSpeed(){
    return speed;
}

public String getTime(){
    return time;
}
```

I understand that the Clip class has to be initialise and i have done that, as well as i do run option 2 first so that the constructor on the other class is not used. I just want it to read in an index number and scan the clip array for a matching index number

Any assistance would help big time

cheers

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the exception, that will tell you which line is causing the problem, which in turn should tell you pretty easily what is `null` that you're expecting not to be.

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the declaration of your array outside the first for loop.

```
Clip[] newClip = new Clip[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 /**/
}
```

Because when you're in the case 3 of your `switch` statement, your looping through all the elements of the array `Clip` (but since you have only set one element of the array, 99 elements of the array are actually set to `null`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating the array every iteration in the loop, so that only the current entry (i) is not `null`.

To fix it, move the line:

```
Clip[] newClip = new Clip[100];
```

needs to be outside the loop (before the `for` statement).

Also, in the loop over `int j`, this will only work if `i == 100`. Not sure if that's guaranteed. Otherwise, the entries in newClip that are after i will also be `null`

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is here:

```
Clip[] newClip = new Clip[100];
```

You need to get that line out of your loop.